Why isn't GitHub Pages a software tool commonly used by programmers?
Why does GitHub Pages only allow the root and "docs" to be the source folder?
This question currently has a score of -10, and is closed for not being about programming or software development.
Why isn't GitHub Pages a software tool commonly used by programmers? How is it different from other github-pages questions? How do you measure "commonly"?

The question you ask on the main site is something only people from GitHub can answer, we don't know why they designed something to work in a particular way. It seems the actual question you want to ask is something like: "How do I use a directory other than the root directory or docs as the source folder for my GitHub pages site?"

I'm not convinced that's really a programming question. IMO, it seems more like a support question on how to use an external service.

No one can really answer why aside GitHub themselves. As written, that is not on-topic

Downvotes often serve as lazy close votes. I don't think it's a "bad" question as in "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful", but as it's worded currently it's off-topic because IMO it's not a programming question.

Close and down votes serve different purposes, @GertArnold ; I don't really see how a down vote can serve as a "lazy" close vote. True, many questions that get closed also get downvoted, but the reasons for the votes differ and opposites can be true as well.

@ThomA You and I know that, but I often see questions downvoted while in my perceptions they should only be closed. And, sadly, close votes are hardly ever explained.

@yivi isn't GitHub Page a software tool commonly used by programmers?

@AbdulAzizBarkat what is the difference with that question?

See also some related Meta questions: Are language specs and their developments on topic?, Is asking "why" on language specifications still considered as "primarily opinion-based" if it can have official answers?, Are "why" questions allowed?

Requirements for being on-topic
The requirements for being on-topic are (emphasis added):

a specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm, or
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

The above text isn't the complete criteria for being on-topic. The linked Help Center "What topics can I ask about here?" page also includes a list of types of questions which are off-topic, even though they fit the above criteria. There's also the "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" page. However, the above criteria are what's relevant here.
GitHub pages are website hosting, which is primarily system administration, not programming
GitHub pages isn't unique to software development. It's a website hosting service. As such, using and configuring GitHub pages is primarily a system administration/configuration task, not programming. That's the same for any hosting service.
There can be tasks within setting up a hosting service which are programming (e.g., writing a script that does some task), but, in general, the configuration of the hosting service isn't actually programming and isn't "unique to software development". That doesn't mean that programmers aren't called on to perform such tasks, just that it's not actually programming or "unique to software development".

Do we have a list of tasks or tools that look like programming but aren't?

@Ooker Not that I'm aware of.

If you quote the help center. But if you quote the close reason description, it becomes "Use this close reason if the question is not about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers". Not the same, far less restrictive.

@Gimby Are you trying to argue that that one option in a popup which has multiple close reason options, including the ability for the user to type in their own text in order to specify anything at all, should be considered the controlling authority of everything that's on-topic instead of the Help Center on-topic page? If that's not what you're trying to communicate, then please clarify.

@Makyen just that it's ambiguous which would explain why there is no consensus on how these kind of situations are handled and interpreted.
